# Display Badges by Rarest on Activity Tab

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

Currently, when viewing other people's profiles, the badges that they have are automatically ordered with the rarest appearing first.  When viewing one's own profile in the "activity" tab, however, the options to sort are only by "recent," "class," and "name."  It would be nice to have a way to see my own badges by rarest as well, in part so that I can more easily get a sense of how much of an "accomplishment" each represents without needing to look each one up separately.  This would be comparable to how it is already possible to display my own questions and answers by their numbers of votes.

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this by visiting [the appropriate tab](/users/current?tab=profile), which displays the view shown by default for other users.